# Как проверить тип объекта во время выполнения программы на C#?

Tags: c#, c#-faq

Как проверить тип объекта во время выполнения программы на C#?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Оператор `is` языка C# проверяет является ли объект экземпляром типа или производного от него типа.

```
if (obj is MyObject)
{
}
```

Справка из MSDN: [оператор is](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/scekt9xw.aspx).

Answer (score 15):

Только `is` вернёт `true`, если `obj` является подклассом `MyObject`, иногда это нежелательно. Для точного сравнения типов пишите так:

```
obj.GetType() == typeof(MyObject)
```

Comment: Если быть совсем уж точным, то `((object)obj).GetType()`, т. к. метод `GetType()` у `obj` может оказаться перегруженным, и возвращать любую ерунду.

Comment: Метод GetType, во-первых, не виртуальный, во-вторых, приведение к базовому типу полиморфизм не прошибёт.

Comment: Это да, но он может быть перекрыт при помощи `new`. https://ideone.com/rG79xt. Мы ж не знаем compile-time-тип `obj`.

Comment: Ну, в принципе, Вы правы. Хотя это маловероятно, конечно, что кто-то будет делать такую подлянку.