# C#. Тип объекта не известен во время компиляции. Какой механизм выбрать?

Tags: c#, динамическая-типизация

Описан класс Volume. Volume содержит атрибут в виде объекта. Этот объект может иметь тип либо BootFAT16 либо BootFAT32 либо BootNTFS и до момента использования этого объекта, какой тип присваивать, будет ясно из условия. И в дальнейшем, в зависимости от типа объекта, он будет обрабатываться по-разному. (Интерфейс я использовать не могу т.к. много методов имеют разную сигнатуру)
Как решаются такие ситуации? Какие механизмы применяют?

Comment: Я бы попытался инкапсулировать работу с `Boot*` в отдельные объекты (обладающие общим интерфейсом), и работал бы через этот интерфейс. Данные, нужные для «методов с разной сигнатурой», должны тоже накапливаться в этих объектах.

Comment: А в чём сложность выделить в интерфейс общую часть, а потом через условия проверять `GetType()` и делать специфичные для объекта действия?

Comment: Проверяйте тип во время выполнения программы и далее предпринимайте необходимую логику в зависимости от типа. [Реализация проверки типа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/436/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D0%BD%D0%B0-c)

Comment: @VladD ответ с примером?

Comment: @andreycha: Сложно объяснить, как свести в общем случае действия с вроде бы разными параметрами к действию с одними и теми же. Лучше бы ТС дал пример кода.

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, что вариант со switch не очень удобный.
Можно использовать словарь с делегатами. Так удобнее добавлять новые обработчики.

```
    public void ProcessBootCommon(object value)
    {
        var bootType = value.GetType();

        //проверка на наличие нужного обработчика
        if (!BootProcessors.ContainsKey(bootType))
            return;

        var processor = BootProcessors[bootType];

        //вызов обработчика
        processor.Invoke(value);
    }

    private Dictionary<Type, Action<object>> BootProcessors = new Dictionary<Type, Action<object>>
    {
        { typeof(BootFat16), ProcessBootFat16}
        //и так далее для каждого типа. Легко добавлять новые обработчики, если вдруг появятся новые типы
    }; 

    private void ProcessBootFat16(object value)
    {
        //Пост проверка. На всякий случай
        if(value.GetType() != typeof(BootFat16))
            return;

        //Код обработки
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

В C# все типы наследуются от базового типа object, используйте его. Ваш код будет примерно такой (C#7):

```
void UseVolume(object volume)
{
    switch(volume)
    {
        case BootFat16 bootFat16:
            BootFat16VolumeProcessor.Process(bootFat16);
            break;
        case BootFat32 bootFat32:
            BootFat32VolumeProcessor.Process(bootFat32);
            break;
        case BootNtfs bootNtfs:
            BootNtfsVolumeProcessor.Process(bootNtfs);
            break;
        default:
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Unknown volume type");
    }
}
```